# Android layout even spacing

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview, imageview

Here's a comparison of what my editor and device is showing:

[image]

The problem is:

- row containing TextView's should take 50% of the screen
- row containing Icon should take remaining 50% of the screen

It works correctly in editor, but as you can see, layout behaves much differently on actual device.

Where's my problem and how to solve it?

Library used for icon is:
https://github.com/code-mc/material-icon-lib

It extends directly from ImageView.

Layout XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/teenSelection"
                android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="TEEN" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/adultSelection"
                android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="ADULT"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/seniorSelection"
                android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="SENIOR"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
            app:materialIcon="check"
            app:materialIconColor="#fff"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try to set android:layout_weight="0.5" in the first TableRow?

Comment: I think the problem is with your  tableRows. you have set the weight to 1, but layout_height is wrap_content. use match_parent instead...

Comment: As Miguel Benitez pointed out, have you tried setting both android_layout_weigth to 0.5?

Comment: problem solved, thank you all for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your TableRow in LinearLayout like this.
i worked. i did test.

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/teenSelection"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/black_slow"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="TEEN" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/adultSelection"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/black_slowest"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="ADULT"/>
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/seniorSelection"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="SENIOR"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
                app:materialIcon="check"
                app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

[image: here is device and editor pic]

Answer (score 2):

you have set your `heights` of the two `TableRows` to `wrap_content`, but they must be `match_parent` like this:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

otherwise the `weight` for the `height` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You should try **PercentRelativeLayout**

in app level **build.gradle** add this

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
```

and change your layout with this.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/teenSelection"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEEN"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/adultSelection"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ADULT"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/seniorSelection"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SENIOR"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
        android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTop"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
        app:materialIcon="check"
        app:materialIconColor="#fff" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you, I already solved it with mehrdad approach.
thank you however for the PercentRelativeLayout, never knew something like this existed ;)